# Display custom option in cart page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I am adding custom option using this code

```
$product->addCustomOption('custom', $id, $product);
```

Its save in database but how to display that custom option in cart item in magento 2?

Comment: No need to add custom code for the custom option and it is a default magento functionality. If you display custom option value and label for the cart page then try this code : $customOptions = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration')->getCustomOptions($_item);

Comment: but i have to add  that custom option  programatically

Comment: try this code : $customOptions = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration')->getCustomOptions($_item);

Comment: If you added custom options with product in cart then display by default in cart view page. see code in file : magento2\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\default.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You can display item option by overriding **Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml** and get the custom option from quote item:

```
<?php
$_item = $block->getItem();
...
?>
...
<!-- Custome code -->
<?php echo $_item->getOptionByCode('custom')->getValue(); ?>
<!-- Custome code -->
```

Comment: We cannot write the php code on html template and seem that the path is wrong.

Comment: You are right, I wrote a wrong file extension. The correct path is Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml, I edited the answer.